# Stat Workflow after certain time if not started already manually

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I have a document library in Sharepoint Online with a Visual Studio Workflow that must be started manually after adding a document to a library. However, I want to automatically start the Workflow after a month if the user did not start it manually himself.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Visual studio Workflows but this is probably a general answer.

- Add option to start manually
- Add option to start workflow when item is created.
  In this workflow, you create a variable with the day of today and add 30 days.
  Then you add an IF condition if the workflow status/completed = untouched/0% and the date +30 == today (the today in a month in the workflow context) ---> start the workflow

I hope this answer helped and is possible in visual studio.